# Нужна ли запятая в предложении со словом "пока"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении: "Пока ему это выгодно(,) он будет продолжать этим заниматься"?

Answer (score 4):

Запятая нужна, это сложноподчиненное предложение.

Пока -здесь союз.

Ср.: П. сын учится, надо ему помочь. П. солнце не взойдёт, на траве лежит иней. Литература существует, п. она понятна.